# Rendering only part of the scene in a rectangle

Tags: opengl, glsl

How would you achieve something like [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUBxHd3bMhg)(from 1:25 on)

I want to try and do something similar but haven't got much clue as to where to begin. I heard about "portal rendering" techniques but I also read it's obsolete technology.

What would be the easiest way to render part of a scene inside a rectangle, clipping the rest of geometry, but still keeping a background behind.

I was told to render the whole scene, but omitting the color fragments and leaving the depth info for the walls. Can you give me a more specific advice here on how to actually do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is render the whole scene, and in the fragment shader use the **discard** statement, if the pixel lies outside the rectangle that you defined. **discard**, as its name implies, discards a pixel and does not write anything to the texture/backbuffer, so your background will be preserved.

If your rectangle is going to change every frame (like in the video), then you are better off to implement this method in a screen-space shader. Then you can use normalized coordinates [0.0 .. 1.0], which would make it a bit easier to determine if the pixel lies outside of a rectangle.

Comment: But wouldn't discarding the pixel also discard it from the depth buffer? I need the "wall" surrounding the scene to actually "be there" in terms of depth so the interior of the scene is not seen outside the walls, but not "be there" for the background.

Comment: First of all, with "scene" you mean that which you want to render (like the portal in the video)? And with background you mean the rest outside the rectangle (like the video itself)? And do you exactly mean with "wall"? I don't understand it completely.

Discarding a pixel does not write anything to the color and depth buffers.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself very clearly. I was thinking of an actual scene where you actually have a box without the front plane, then the "walls" surrounding its interior don't get drawn, but they do occlude the interior. I guess that's not what you were telling me.

Comment: Ah ok, but I still don't see how the inner walls of the box occlude the interior (where the scene needs to be drawn. The front plane of the box is the rectangle on which the scene will be rendered, or am I wrong?

Comment: Because if that is true, then you discard anything outside of this rectangle, and inside the rectangle you set the depth to 1 ('infinitely' close to the screen) and render the scene.